# stuck transaction

Tags: wallets, cpp-ethereum, bscscan

I made a Gnosis wallet with some friends and basically what ended up happening was that we accidently sent a txn via the eth network to our wallet instead of sending the funds thru BSC network. We need want to get those funds back and its a multisig wallet.